# Moving folders between sites add them inside the source recycle bin, unlike moving the folder to another library within the same site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have noted this inside our SharePoint online document library; Moving folders between sites will add the moved folders and files inside the source recycle bin, unlike moving the folder to another library within the same site where the folders will not get added inside the recycle bin. is this normal behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, the **Move to** option in the document library could move the file or folder normally.

[image]

[image]

Comment: and what is the relation between your answer and my question?